# Sorting rows in datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable where I would like to move all the rows that have a certain firstname and lastname to the top of the table.

```
public DataTable SortByFirstNameAndLastNameMatch(DataTable table, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        DataTable ret = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in table.Rows)
        {
            if (dataRow["NomArtiste"].ToString().ToLower() == lastName.ToLower() && dataRow["PrenomArtiste"].ToString().ToLower() == firstName.ToLower())
            {
                ret.ImportRow(dataRow);
            }
        }

        ret.Merge(table);
        return RemoveDuplicateRows(ret, "AlbumID");
    }
```

Is there a way I can do this using a linq expression or a comparer without making a new datatable?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the order *in the database*? Or just *get* and ordered result?

Comment: Well, I guess see DataViews/[DefaultView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx) - that may work for you. (You must use the DataView and *not* the natural ordering, however!)

Comment: If you use `.AsEnumerable()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) on the `DataTable` then you can apply all the LINQ sorting/filtering/transforming/etc. that you want on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new DataView on your DataTable and apply whatever sorting and filtering you see fit.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx for an example.

Alternatively you can do it with LINQ:

```
var sortedTableQuery = table.OrderBy(r => r["NomArtiste"].ToString() == lastName ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(r => r["PrenomArtiste"].ToString() == firstName ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(r => r["NomArtiste"].ToString()).ThenBy(r => r["PrenomArtiste"].ToString());
var a = sortedTableQuery.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

In Linq, it would look something like this:

```
var sortedNames = unsortedNames.OrderBy(n => n == lastName ? 1 : 2).ThenBy(n => n == firstName ? 1 : 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataView dv=datatable.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "ColumnName Asc ,ColumnName Asc, ColumnName Asc , ColumnName Asc";
datatable=dv.toTable().Copy();
```